# Magento 2: Default stock issue after products import using magmi?

Tags: magento2, magmi

I have tried to import product **CSV file** using a magmi but somehow it's not assigned Default stock value. For that, I need to re-save the product from admin then after it will add into the cart.

I have also tried to add quantity, is_in_stock column in **CSV** file but it's not working.

**have any idea, please share.**

[image]

Comment: Check if this would help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/34263210/1796778

Comment: @ShoaibMunir I have tried with suggested CSV but still getting same issue.

Comment: I think you need to save a product manually or programmatically using script.

Answer (score 0):

> Run Below SQL:

```
    Insert into `inventory_source_item` (source_code, sku, quantity, status)
    Select 'default', sku, qty, stock_status from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` as `lg` join `catalog_product_entity` as `prd`
    on ((`lg`.`product_id` = `prd`.`entity_id`))) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = VALUES(quantity), status = VALUES(status);

    UPDATE `inventory_source_item` SET `status`=0 WHERE `quantity`<=0;

    UPDATE `inventory_source_item` SET `status`=1 WHERE `quantity` > 0;
```

use_config_manage_stock = '1';

manage_stock = '1';

is_in_stock = 1

quantity = 100